# exporting data from apex pmd view in eclipse

Tags: apex, eclipse

[image: ApexPMD View in Eclipse]
Please suggest any method to get this data from ApexPMD view in excel sheet, using any script or tweak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a command line PMD:

Download PMD From here :- 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

> You should have Java 1.8 correctly configured on Your local machine.

Go TO >> BIN >> Enter CMD in folder path, to open Command Line Editor  
Execute Following Command

> pmd -d "Your Project Directory Path till src" -R apex-ruleset -language apex -f
>   csv > "Report Folder Path\PMDReportName.csv"

OR

> pmd -d "Your Project Directory Path till src" -R apex-ruleset -language apex -f
>   html > "Report Folder Path\PMDReportName.html"

You will get the report in your folder for the project that you are working either in CSV or HTML format depending upon the format you are specifying in the command.

Thanks,
Nachiket