# PMD Apex static code analyser on Mac

Tags: apex, pmd

I have used [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) before on Windows. I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqhjI4i1eyo) very helpful for advising me of the correct PMD command to input for Windows.

I want to use PMD on Mac. I have installed PMD (I know it's installed because by inputting 'pmd pmd -help', I get info) but I am not able to give the correct PMD terminal command.

I used the format below on Windows and it worked correctly:

```
pmd –d “[Your path to the folder, for example pmdCodeAnalysis]” – f html –R “[Your path to pmdCodeAnalysis\Rules\ApexRules.xml” –reportfile “..\PMDOutput.html”
```

but inputting what I perceive to be the Mac equivalent doesn't work.

```
pmd pmd -ls /Users/andyhitchings/Desktop/pmd/Code -f html -R /Users/andyhitchings/Desktop/pmd/Rules/ApexRules.xml -reportfile “../pmdOutput.html”
```

Can anyone advise what the correct command should be to get PMD to work on Mac?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you try this ?
pmd -d "Project Dir Path till src" -R apex-ruleset -language apex -f html > "Report Folder Path\PMDReport.html"

Comment: you must have downloaded PMD, open bin folder inside that and from that same path open Command Prompt and execute above command.

Comment: I'm not at my Mac to look, but as a side note, there are plugins for both Eclipse and Visual Studio Code to run PMD in the IDE.

Comment: Hi @NachiketDeshpande - I have tried the following but none work. The error is 'the following option is required: - rulesets, -R'. pmd -d "\Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\6.2.0\bin\Code\1.apxc.java” -R apex-ruleset -language apex -f html > "\Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\6.2.0\bin\PMDReport.html THEN pmd -d "\Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\6.2.0\bin\Code\1.apxc.java” -f html -R “\Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\Rules\ApexRules.xml” -f html > "\Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\6.2.0\bin\PMDReport.html

Comment: are you executing command through path of bin folder ?

Comment: check my answer it may help you https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165038/exporting-data-from-apex-pmd-view-in-eclipse/165047#165047

Comment: @AndyHitchings
can you share me following :- 
1. Your Source Code Folder Path.
2. Your Report Folder Path where you want your report to be stored after execution of PMD commands
Looks like something is wrong with your command, you need to enter exactly same command with commas and all

Comment: \Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\6.2.0\bin\Code\1.apxc.java , is this a correct path where you have added your source code to scan ?

Comment: Hi @NachiketDeshpande. Thanks for your help here. 1) /Users/andyhitchings/Desktop/pmd/6.2.0/bin/Code/1.apxc 2) /Users/andyhitchings/Desktop/pmd/6.2.0/bin/reportInfo. And I am inputting the command from this path in terminal: /Users/andyhitchings/Desktop/pmd/6.2.0/bin

Comment: The command line arguments don't change. `-d` is always `-d`; it would never change to `-ls`.

Comment: Did you check https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.3.0/pmd_userdocs_getting_started.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many fragments of your command look wrong when I compare it to what I normally use and what is described here in the docs:https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.3.0/pmd_userdocs_getting_started.html

E.g. there is no -ls parameter. You have to use -d as in Windows. I highly recommend starting with a simple command where no reports are written to boil down the problem to a specific fragment.

```
$ ./bin/run.sh pmd -d ../../../src/classes/ -f html -R rulesets/apex/basic.xml -language apex
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Robert! I have now got this brilliant tool working on mac. The command I used in the end was: pmd pmd -d  ../../codeX -R /Users/andyhitchings/Desktop/pmd/Rules/ApexRules.xml -language apex -f html > /Users/andyhitchings/Desktop/pmdReport.html from the bin folder of the PMD directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command, you need to input this from `bin` folder of your `PMD`

> pmd -d "Project Dir Path till src" -R apex-ruleset -language apex -f
>   html > "Report Folder Path\PMDReport.html"

How I execute this command to scan my source code from local drive

> ```
> pmd -d "C:\Demo Folder\src" -R apex-ruleset -language apex -f html > "C:\Users\Nachiket\Desktop\Reports\PMDReportName.html"
> ```

Where,

`Project Dir Path till src` -- >  `"C:\Demo Folder\src"` I have my source code stored here, C drive, folder name `"Demo Folder"`

`"Report Folder Path\PMDReport.html"` -- >  `"C:\Users\Nachiket\Desktop\Reports\PMDReportName.html"`, I want to store my report here after PMD command finishes its execution.

In Your case,

> pmd -d "Project Dir Path till src" -R apex-ruleset -language apex -f
>   html > "Report Folder Path\PMDReport.html"

you can  execute this command like following to scan your source code from local drive

> pmd -d "\Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\6.2.0\bin\Code\1.apxc" -R
>   apex-ruleset -language apex -f html >
>   "\Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\6.2.0\bin\reportInfo\PMDReportName.html"

Where,

`Project Dir Path till src` -- >  `"\Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\6.2.0\bin\Code\1.apxc"` You have your source code stored here.

`"Report Folder Path\PMDReport.html"` -- >  `"\Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\6.2.0\bin\reportInfo\PMDReportName.html"`, You want to store your report here after PMD command finishes its execution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, i'm still returning an error. A file is created but it reads: '-d is NOT a valid application name, valid options are:pmd, cpd, cpdgui, designer, bgastviewer, designerold'.

Comment: \Users\andyhitchings\Desktop\pmd\6.2.0\bin\Code\1.apxc , is this a correct path, do you have your source code stored in PMD bin folder and what type of file 1.apxc is  ?
can you try by 1.cls

Comment: @AndyHitchings or try removing your file out of PMD folder,apex class are stored with extension as .cls

Comment: thanks for your help but it still doesn't work. The command just hangs and I don't get the expected output. PMD works flawlessly on Windows but it doesn't work well on Mac, at least for me. Also, on Mac, I can't get PMD to work with Eclipse. Frustrating to say the least. Thanks for your efforts and help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the SFDX-CLI code scanner instead of running PMD on your own. You should be able to install this into your CI runner and do a force installation.

[SFDX-CLI Scanner](https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-scanner/en/scanner-commands/run/)